# Space at begin of paragraph

Tags: latex

Hello im doing a project for my university in latex and came accross this problem and nothing to fix it.
Basically there is this white space bevore the beginning of each paragraph. Below is my latex code from this sheet.

[image: compiled pdf]

```
einem Ausgabeneuron. Gewichte in Neuronalen Netzen sind reelle Zahlen, unter denen man sich die Wichtigkeit der jeweiligen Eingabe vorstellen kann. Ändert man die Gewichte der einzelnen Eingabeneuronen, beeinflusst man somit die spätere Aktivierung des Ausgabeneurons. Die Ausgabe $y$ wird bestimmt durch die Aktivierungsfunktion des Ausgabeneurons und ist dabei wie folgt definiert: \\
%Output gleichung
\begin{equation}
    y =
    \begin{cases}
      0, & \text{wenn}\ $$\sum_{i} w_{i}x_{i} \leq Schwellwert$$ \\
      1, & \text{andernfalls}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}\\

Dabei ist der Schwellwert Teil des jeweiligen Neurons. Wie bei den Eingaben und Gewichtungen handelt es sich bei dem Schwellwert auch um eine reelle Zahl, welche anpassbar ist, um unterschiedliche Ergebnisse zu erzwingen. Worin besteht nun der Unterschied zu einem Multilayer Perzeptron? \\

Die Aktivierungsfunktion eines Multilayer Perzeptrons springt nicht zwischen 0 und 1, wie in (1) definiert sondern verhält sich stetig. \\
Das Singlelayer Perzeptron ist in der Lage, linear separierbare Probleme, wie z.B. die AND Funktion, zu lösen. Hier lassen sich die Resultatrelationen klar durch eine Gerade trennen. Bei der XOR Funktion reicht eine Gerade nicht mehr aus, ein Singlelayer Perzeptron wäre also nicht in der Lage, die XOR Funktion zu lösen.
```

Comment: please make a [mre] instead of this non-compilable code fragment

Comment: unrelated to your problem, but don't use `$$....$$` in latex, don't put whole words like `Schwellwert` in math font (this will mess up the kerning) and instead of manually referring to think like `(1)`, better have a look at the `\label{...}`/`\ref{...}` mechanism to get the numbering automatically right

Comment: and don't abuse `\\ ` for line breaks (with the exception of tabulars)

Answer (score 0):

Add `\usepackage{parskip}` to your preamble. For further customisation options see the [`parskip` documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/parskip?lang=en).